# GET-параметры в JSF

Tags: jsf, java

Переписываю один проект на JSF 2.0, поэтому должен следовать правилам MVC.
В упрощенном виде есть ManagedBean User со свойством `String login`. И есть представление `user.xhtml`, которое мапится на `user.jsf`.

Как лучше всего со стороны парадигмы MVC организовать передачу параметра `login` для того, чтоб представление `user.jsf` могло отобразить информацию о конкретном пользователе?

Классическое решение `user.jsf?login=login`, как я понимаю, не самое лучшее?
Или возможно нужно использовать сервлет, который будет устанавливать в сессии параметр и будет форвардить запрос на `user.jsf`?

Answer (score 1):

"Классическое решение" вполне приемлемо, тем более URL страницы пользователя может быть статическим.

Чем `myservlet?login=login`, который установит переменную в сессию и перенаправит на `user.jsf` будет отличаться от `user.jsf?login=login`? Переменная `login` в сессии Вам тоже не нужна. (Свои сервлеты в JSF нет смысла использовать)

Получить этот параметр можно так:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="login" value="#{user.login}" />
</f:metadata>
```

либо

```
@ManagedProperty(value="#{param.login}")
private String login;
```